# column width in rich:datatable

Tags: css, richfaces, jsf-2

How to set the colum width for a `rich:column` inside a `rich:datatable` ? The `width` attribute is being ignored. See the following code:

```
<rich:column label="#{msg[result]}" width="150px">
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="#{veryLongText}"/>
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{someValue}" /> 
<f:facet name="footer">
    <h:outputText value="#{someValue}" /> 
</f:facet>
</rich:column>
```

If you render this column and `veryLongText` is wider than 150px it does not break it in multiple lines. Instead, it just ignores the column width and takes as much as space needed.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the `<rich:column>`'s `headerClass` attribute, as so:

```
<rich:column headerClass="myWidth">
...
</rich:column>
```

Then, in your CSS (embedded or linked):

```
.myWidth {width:150px}
```

You may also have some contravening "white-space" CSS property coming into play somewhere, so you might want to specify the `.myWidth` selector as so:

```
.myWidth {width:150px; white-space:normal!important}
```

Answer (score 3):

use:

`style="width:150px"`

or `styleClass="myColumnClass"`
where you add in your CSS

```
.myColumnClass{
 width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Nop, that does not work. Column width is still as wide as `veryLongText`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to achieve columns with word-wrap use  this one....

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;width: 300px;word-wrap: break-word; ">
  <h:outputText value="#{someValue}" />
</div>
```

It is tested on both Mozilla and IE 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
<rich:column width="60px">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{veryLongText}" />
    </f:facet>
    <div style="overflow:hidden;width:60px">
         <h:outputText value="#{someValue}" />
    </div>
</rich:column>
```