# width of column in rich:datatable

Tags: css, jsf

I am using JSF 1.2, in one of my web page i am using . I want to set column's width.

```
<rich:dataTable id="dt" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <rich:column filterBy="" filterEvent="onkeyup" sortBy=""> 
    <f:facet name="header1">
       <h:outputText value="header1" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="myValue1"></h:outputText>
   </rich:column>
   <rich:column filterBy="" filterEvent="onkeyup" sortBy=""> 
    <f:facet name="header2">
       <h:outputText value="header2" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="myValue2"></h:outputText>
   </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

In one of rich:column i need to set width for column, for this i tried like

1) `width="100px"`

2) `headerClass="myWidth"` and declared  `myWidth` in css file, 
        `.myWidth {width:100px;}`  (as mentioned in
    [column width in rich:datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512682/column-width-in-richdatatable))
    but both did not work.

can anyone help me to set column width.

Comment: i also tried columnsWidth option in <rich:dataTable> and set width for every column, but it also did not worke.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512682/column-width-in-richdatatable/3527721#3527721

Comment: Sorry for duplicat question. First i serach question and i also try to implement solution provided in that question, but somehow it did not work for me. Even in my question i have given link to that question column width in rich:datatable (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512682/column-width-in-richdatatable). I am still trying to solve this. please anybody help

Comment: Did u get any answer for above question actually the problem is with sortBy attribute if we remove that everything is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use columnClasses attribute of rich:dataTable and give a class or same class for each column.

```
<rich:dataTable columnClasses="col1Class,col2Class" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set width of selected columns then another option that **rich:dataTable** provides is you can do something like this:

```
<rich:dataTable id="dt" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <rich:column filterBy="" filterEvent="onkeyup" sortBy="" styleClass="column1"> 
    <f:facet name="header1">
      <h:outputText value="header1" />
     </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="myValue1"></h:outputText>
  </rich:column>
  <rich:column filterBy="" filterEvent="onkeyup" sortBy="" styleClass="column2"> 
     <f:facet name="header2">
       <h:outputText value="header2" />
     </f:facet>
     <h:outputText value="myValue2"></h:outputText>
 </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

now you can easily define not just the width but any CSS property that you want using CSS class selector
eg;

```
.column1{
    width:30%;
}
```